# Find $E[X^2 + Y^2]$ for the given joint density function.

Tags: probability

Let X and Y have joint probability density function

$f(x,y) = \frac{3}{2}(x^2 +y^2)$, with $0<x<1, 0<y<1$.

Find $E[X^2+Y^2]$.

I came up with $\frac{14}{15}$ by integrating $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x^2 +y^2)(x^2+y^2)$, but I've
never had  to do anything but E[X].

Comment: That's what I get.

Comment: Noticing that $E[X^2]=E[Y^2],  E[X^2+Y^2]=2E[X^2]$ will help with the computations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{E}[\varphi(X,Y)] = \int \int_{D} \varphi(x,y) f(x,y) dx dy = \frac{3}{2} \int _{0}^{1} \int _{0}^{1}(x^4 + 2 x^2  y^2 + y^4)dx dy = \frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{1}[\int_{0}^{1}(x^4 + 2 x^2  y^2 + y^4)dy]dx$

Are you familiar with double integration? Can you handle from here?

Comment: Yes. This is what I did, I just wasn't sure if I was supposed to integrate $xf(x,y)$ vs. $(x^2 +y^2)f(x,y)$.

Comment: Do you understand now?

Comment: I understand yes. Integration isn't a problem, it was determining the integrand.